# How to auto-complete all columns in "select * from table" in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: t-sql, ssms

Write this:

```
    Select      *         From tablea
```

Want this:

```
    Select c1, c2, c3 ... From tablea
```

SQL Server Management Studio provides intellisense to pick one column at a time. It takes a while for table with lots of columns.

I can use Script Table as =>Select To=> New Query Edit Window, and the copy/paste to my original script. however is there a less interruptive way?

I write SQL a lots, thanks for help!

Comment: The native functionality does not exist but there are tools like RedGate's SQL Prompt that are able to do it.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Found this myself.

1. Type `Select * From TableA` in SSMS.
2. Exactly Select text `Select * From TableA`.
3. Use `Ctrl+Shift+Q` to pop up Query Designer window.
4. Click OK. "*" is replaced by "c1, c2, c3..."

Query Designer auto-populates all the columns. just open it & close. if you want only portion of columns, I found it is still easier to delete them on text editor than trying to use mouse to uncheck them on GUI.

Still hope to find a way to eliminate the Keyboard/mouse switch on step 4? seems there is no short-cut key for the OK button.

**Update 2019-06-24**

Above method does not work for [table in SQL Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474205/design-in-query-editor-disabled-for-azure-databases). ApexSQL [SQL formatter](https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-refactor.aspx) seems working well for me, it's <strike>free</strike>.

[image]

**Update 2020-10-30**

found a similar function in LINQPad, it allows me to auto-complete all properties in LINQ, [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64614031/2055187)

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer I found because it works for temporary tables and other intermediate results (sub-selects, etc.). It appears to run off the same machinery that Intellisense does and does not require the tables to exist on their own.

Comment: If you add an alias to your table ALL of the fields are populated without the alias.  Not a deal breaker but still... now I have to go in and copy/paste the alias to each field.

Answer (score 6):

In SQL Server Management Studio if you expand the object explorer and then the node for the particular table in question then you can drag the columns node into the query window and this will type out all of the column names for you.

There are probably better ways to do this, but that's what I use.

Comment: That's the only built-in way (except the Script as option), but it's pretty neat.

Comment: I have to first un-select the asterisk "All" column (first row) using Ctrl + Click before dragging the selection, otherwise it fills all the "Alias" columns with useless aliases, such as Expr1, Expr2, Expr3, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Totally understand this answer is not specific to `SSMS` but in `VSCode` via the mssql extension:

Write this:

```
Select *
From TableX
```

Place cursor after the `*` and press Ctrl+Spacebar and option to insert all columns appears

Answer (score -1):

If your object explorer is open then use drag & drop feature.

e.g. Northwind

Step 1: Expand the database by single click on plus icon or just double click on "Northwind"
Step 2: Expand tables "Tables"

Now you will see "Columns", "Keys", "Constraints" etc

Click on "Columns" to drag to your editor window.

You can try for other as well like "Keys", "Constraints".

But for "Indexes", did not work for me.

Hope you will find useful tips.

Comment: This is the same answer as posted by @PaulMcLaughlin a week earlier.