# Design in Query Editor disabled for Azure databases

Tags: azure, ssms-2012, azure-sql-database

When I try to manage an Azure Database query in SQL Managements Studio 2012 I see that the "Design in Query Editor" option is disabled. It is enabled for other databases but not for Azure. Is there a way to enable it?

Thanks

[image: Feature Disabled]

Comment: I just want to say that it appears to be exactly the same problem in all SSMS versions after 2012, including the newly available v18.0 preview 4. Does microsoft intend to do something regarding this ? Interestingly, the query designer is still available when clicking on "New view" option in DB Views. It can still be used as a workaround.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is a by design issue. Not all SSMS functionality from on-premise SQL Server is supported when connected to Azure SQL database, "Design Query in Edit" greys out because it's not supported for azure sql database. For more information, please refer to this thread: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/22d29cb7-48d1-4cbd-af2e-30b66ebdc7d4/ssmss-design-query-in-editor-greyed-out?forum=sqltools

Comment: The thread you mention suggests using the web portal for editing queries but I can't figure out how.

Comment: On the web portal, click on your database > Tools > Open in Visual Studio, then you can design your query in Visual Studio, but there is no "Deisgn Query in Editor" option neither.

Answer (score 4):

As @forester123 mentioned this is not supported for Azure databases. But there's a workaround!

In object explorer, collapse the database you want and right click "Views" and click "New View...". Here you can have access to a query designer view. As long as you do not save it, then it works as a query designer.

[image]

Comment: You save my Day I totally forgot about View

Answer (score 0):

It indeed is disabled for Azure SQL, but (at least in version 18.12.1), when you click on **New Query** from the toolbar, while it's setting up the connection, there is a brief moment when it's available and working.
But after you close it, it's greyed out again.