# Visual Query Designer for Azure SQL Database?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

SQL Management Studio's visual Query Designer is not supported for Azure SQL Database (PaaS), as mentioned in this question: [Design in Query Editor disabled for Azure databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35474205/design-in-query-editor-disabled-for-azure-databases)

As some of the members of our team rely extensively on visual query designers, I am looking for a tool that will provide similar functionality to SSMS's Query Designer but that will work with Azure SQL Database. Ideally this tool would be free to use, although this is not a deal breaker.

I looked into FlySpeed SQL Query (https://www.activedbsoft.com/features-querytool.html) but this appears only to work with SQL Server in Azure, not Azure SQL itself. Apart from that I'm struggling to find anything else that even appears to do what I need.

Is this something that is possible with any tool that is currently available?

Answer (score 5):

You could not use the Design in Query Editor directly in a query, however you could enable it in the view.

I'm using SSMS 17, you could enable query designer for SQL Azure by right-clicking on the `views` folder on your DB and selecting `new view`.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks @George Chen. We're looking for an option that works for all queries and not just Views. Do you know if that's possible? Thanks!

Comment: @Matt Shepherd, this is the only way I know to use Query Designer,  cause not all SSMS functionality from on-premise SQL Server is supported when connected to Windows Azure SQL Database (SQL Azure), the only requirement is add a new view.

Comment: @Matt Shepherd, if you insist to use this function on SSMS, you could vote up in the feedback page to let Azure knows . https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/13699062-design-query-in-editor

Comment: @Matt Shepherd, if this could help you, you could mark it as the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I tried DBeaver, which has good reviews. But couldn't get it to connect to Azure SQL. SSMS did connect for me, though !!!

Answer (score 0):

We use DBSchema to visualize the database schema and to build queries using the visual query builder. DBSchema quickly reverse engineers the schema into a model. In addition DBSchema uses the foreign keys to aid you in writing queries that get data from several tables.

https://dbschema.com/

[image: DBSchema Screenshot]

DBSchema stores its models in an XML file that can easily be added to a git repo. This allows tracking of the model versions.